# Instantiating and initialiazing an array of objects with 1 line of code

Tags: java, arrays

First things first I apologize if the title is misleading. I would like to implement my own version of Minesweeper in Java. When I created an array of objects and tested one of my functions i got a NullPointerException. Browsing Stack Overflow I managed to solve my problem. However it turns out that the array must first be instantiated and then initialized. So what I am asking is the following: Can I instantiate an object array and initialize it at the same time?

MineSweeperMain.java

```
public class MineSweeperMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MineSweeper ms = new MineSweeper(9,9);
        int test;
        for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
            {
                ms.tile[i][j]=new Tile(); // can I initialize the array in the same line that I am instantiating it using the default constructor? 
            }
        test = ms.tile[0][0].getNeighbours();
        System.out.println("Test: " + test);
    }
}
```

Tile.java

```
public class Tile {
    int numNeighbours;
    boolean hasBomb;

    Tile() {
        numNeighbours = 0;
        hasBomb = false;
    }


    int getNeighbours() {
        return numNeighbours;
    }

    boolean hasBomb() {
        return hasBomb;
    }
}
```

Minesweeper.java

```
public class MineSweeper {
    Tile tile[][];

    MineSweeper(int x,int y) {
        tile = new Tile[x][y];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Using `tile[9][9]();` does not work either.

Comment: Where are you trying to do this, and what do you expect it to look like? Your code seems fine. I'm unclear on what you don't like about it. Is it the for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are trying to do...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        MineSweeper ms = new MineSweeper(9,9);
        int test;
        // remove code here
        test = ms.tile[0][0].getNeighbours();
        System.out.println("Test: " + test);
    }

public class MineSweeper {
    Tile tile[][];

    MineSweeper(int x,int y) {
        tile = new Tile[x][y];
        // create Tiles here
        for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<y;j++)
                tile[i][j]=new Tile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, this is a nice way to make things prettier. But I was just asking if there is a way syntax wise to instantiate and initialize the array in just 1 line without using loops. It's fine if  there isn't a way to do this, I was just asking out of pure curiosity.

Comment: AFAIK, no, if you don't create the instances they will all be null.

Comment: @John the reason there isn't such a syntax is that not all classes have an empty constructor.

Comment: @MadPhysicist oops :) thanks for mentioning. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's nothing wrong with 2 nested `for` loops to fill elements of your two-dimensional array.

However, it is possible to use Java streams to generate new Tiles in a 2D array.

Start with code for a `Stream` to generate a 1D array of `Tile`s.

```
Tile[] oneDArray = Stream.generate(Tile::new).limit(9).toArray(Tile[]::new);
```

Then you can use that expression to tell an outer `Stream` how to generate one-dimensional arrays as part of the overall two-dimensional array.

```
Tile[][] tile = Stream.<Tile[]>generate(
        () -> Stream.generate(Tile::new).limit(x).toArray(Tile[]::new)
    ).limit(y).toArray(Tile[][]::new);
```

For type inference purposes I had to supply the `Tile[]` type argument explicitly.

I've written it as multiple lines, but it's all one statement.  Whichever way you choose, nested `for` loops or this streaming solution, the code can also be moved into your `Minesweeper` constructor so that it's hidden from the `main` code.

Comment: Thanks that was very informative. Frankly,  I expected there was a simpler way of doing this, using streams is kinda complicated. I will stick with standard for loops, it is easier to use loops in comparison to an inner and an outer stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList.
Inside your minesweeper class should live an arraylist of tiles.
Have the constructor of Minesweeper call a method that fills the arraylist with tiles.
Give each tile an X and Y coordinate.
Then in order to get neighbors, just loop through the tiles arraylist and tyle.getX and tyle.getY to determine if it boarders... or if it is a bomb.. or if it was flipped already.

ArrayList tiles = new ArrayList();

for.....

Tile tile = new Tile(X,Y)

tiles.add(tile)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. But in fact i was asking something different. I am just wondering if there is a way to avoid instantiating the array and initializing it in just 1 line of code. Tried using tile[x][y]() hoping that this would create a tile array of x * y dimensions and then initializing it using the default constructor, but to no avail.

Comment: A 2D array is a much more appropriate storage for a fixed sized board

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you please explain why? Is it faster performance wise? Easier to understand syntax wise? Or is it just for simplicity?

Comment: I think that is the hang up. Tile tile[][];
A standard array has an initial size and that's it. you have to Dimension it to size. Use an arraylist instead.  ms.getTylesArrayList.add(new Tile(x,y))

Comment: An ArrayList is fundamentally a variable sized container, trading allocation and access efficiency for convenience. Am array is a fixed sized container. When you have fundamentally fixed sized data, an array is clearly the better choice

Comment: Also, lists aren't nearly as convenient in multiple dimensions as arrays.